# prompting for input and output to a file in cmake

Tags: cmake

i'm working with cmake for the first time, and I'm trying to do something simple. Let's say there are some dependencies needed for the project that are installed in a directory that is abnormal for a library, but the user knows exactly where they are. For example i have a project i am working on that requires SFML, but i always install all of my API's and libraries in the same directory, c:/dev. That way i don't have tons of libraries all disorganized around my computer. The problem is i want cmake to find that library, but find_module will not look there and won't find it. My question is this. If someone puts all their API's and libraries in a different folder, is there anyway i can query the user for that path just once when they pull down my project via git or something and try to build?

Step by step i want this. Run cmake, cmake tries to find_module for a dependency needed, if it fails, it asks the user if they know and they type in a path. If it still can't find it, it fails, and if it does, it stores that path in a file somewhere so that subsequent calls to cmake will not query for it, and i would do this for each dependency. Is this possible? This is never really a problem on unix systems, but it's a real problem for me on windows because every library seems to want to install in different and random locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake does not provide interactive dialogs, so you can't prompt the user for input. With the grapgical front-ends (`ccmake` and `cmake-gui`) the user can manually enter the library paths into the correct variables, but this is not very convenient and already requires some knowledge of CMake and the find scripts being used.

I personally found the use of environment variables to be the most comfortable solution for this on Windows. Most of the find scripts that ship with CMake already support this. You setup one environment variable for each library, pointing to the path where that library is located. You only have to do this once on each machine and will be able to run CMake automatically afterwards. It's still not as comfortable as the default paths on Linux, but this is as good as it gets on Windows.

You can add some custom [`message`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3amessage) output (eg. "`SFML could not be found - set the SFML_DIR environment variable to point to the correct location`") to make it more obvious for users what they have to do to get it running correctly.

Comment: I believe this will work out just fine. I don't want the user to have to edit the CMakeList.txt in any way so an end user won't push a change that might break it, but i can leave specific instructions somewhere that if you have a library in a weird place, just set the cached variable in the cmake-gui. I found out that the FindSFML.cmake file they provide has a variable you can set for just such a thing, SFML_ROOT, which worked nicely. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

If you want cmake `execute_process` to be interactive and prompt the user for some data, that is definitely possible. Here's an example using bash.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(go LANGUAGES NONE)

find_program(BASH NAMES bash bash.exe
PATHS "c:/msys64/usr/bin" "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/Git/bin"
)

# message("#BASH ${BASH}")

execute_process(COMMAND "${BASH}" "-c"
[=[
>&2 echo ""
names=("aaa"
       "bbb"
       "ccc")

num=-1
for x in "${names[@]}"; do
    ((num++))
    >&2 echo "$num. $x"
done
>&2 echo -n "Choose (0-$num) -> "
read var
re_number='^[0-9]+$'
if [[ ( "$var" =~ $re_number ) &&  ( "$var" -ge 0 ) && ( "$var" -le "$num" ) ]]; then
    echo "${names[$var]}"
else
    echo "error"
    exit 1
fi
]=]
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE output
                #OUTPUT_FILE /dev/stdout
                RESULT_VARIABLE ret_code
                OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
                ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
                )


message("### output == ${output}")
message("### ret_code == ${ret_code}")
```

The trick is to output all stuff on stderr which is what this does `>& echo "this goes to stderr"`, and have stuff you want to capture via `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` go to stdout (with a normal `echo`).